# MySQL IN query running slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have read some articles on here and they don't answer my question. I realize `IN` is a slow  clause but I cannot figure a way around using it in my case.

Here is my MYSQL Query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(t.id) as id, t.t_name as name, t.t_city as city, 
(count(pd.rs)) as pdc FROM #__bl_teams as t Left JOIN #__bl_paid as pd ON pd.t_id = t.id
 AND pd.rs=1 AND ((MID(pd.r_date,1,10)) >= t.start_date) 
WHERE(t.id IN($teams)) 
GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY name ASC";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $players = $db->loadObjectList();
```

My problem is the `Where (t.id IN $teams)`
`$teams` is 600 items in a Comma separated string.

This is taking way too long to perform the query. Any ideas how I could work around the "IN" clause?

Comment: Of course you've escaped and encoded `$teams` correctly, so no chance of SQL injection?

Comment: Is the `IN` part slow? What if you check only 60 items? Much faster?

Comment: I need to check the entire 600. Is there a way to only check 60 at a time, then combine?

Comment: 600 items in an IN clause is something quite hard to process, I run into something similar, the more you have the more slow it becomes.

Comment: You could put all the $teams content in a temporary table with an index and join it to your #bl_teams table - might be considerably faster.

Comment: Have you done an explain on the query, (just tap a few in as an exmaple, few other things that could be slowing this query down..

Comment: I will try Explain. I am looking up temporary tables now